# Как организовать временное хранение данных внутри программы?

Tags: java

Есть программа расчета расходов и давлений гидравлических агрегатов. Программа старая с интерфейсом в виде псевдографики, жутко неудобная и т.д. (написана, говорят, на клиппере - не совсем в курсе что это - система старше меня самого). В общем нужно написать ее современный аналог с адекватным интерфейсом и прочими плюшками. 
В данной программе пользователь вводит исходные данные в текстовый файл, который собственно программа читает, встречает определенные символы, на этом основании принимает решение, какой тип строки, тип параметра и т.д.

Вот пример исходных данных:

T42 PMAX60 G55 C6621103
POZ1                 
GP1                  
IM N601 D63 W32      
PR L360 H15 B2 K5    
OB L360 H15 S6 K10   
IM N602 D80 W40      
PR L160 H15 B2 K4    
OB L160 H15 S7 K9    
IM N603 D80 W40      
PR L50 H15 B2.5 K3   
OB L50 H15 S5 K5.5   
IM N11 D25 W14       
PR L16 H15 B4 K5     
OB L16 H15 S6 K7     
IM N12 N13 D32 W16   
PR L70 H15 B0 K1     
OB L70 H15 S5 K6     
IM N14 D16 W10       
PR L13 H15 S11 K12   
OB L13 H15 B15 K16   
IM N15 N16 D25 W14   
PR L12 H15 S14 K16   
OB L12 H15 B18 K20   
IM N17 D40 W20       
PR L220 H15 B12 K14  
OB L220 H15 S16 K18  
IM N51 D100 W70      
PR L68 H15 B11 K13   
PR L32 P150 B13 K25  
OB L90 H15 S27 K28.5 
OB L10 H15 S28.5 K29 
IM N52 D100 W70      
PR L62 H15 B11 K13   
PR L38 P150 B13 K27  
OB L90 H15 S29 K30.5 
OB L10 H15 S30.5 K31 
IM N53 D50 W25       
PR L80 H15 B9 K10    
OB L80 H15 S26 K27   
IM N54 D50 W25       
PR L80 H15 B9 K10    
OB L80 H15 S28 K29

Как видно, здесь есть несколько типов строк (6, если быть более точным), есть строки, которые встречаются только один раз, есть повторяющиеся, повторяются произвольно. У каждого типа строки есть один или несколько параметров, некоторые параметры могут отсутствовать (отсутствующие параметры не принимаются во внимание при расчете).
Тип строки определяется первым словом (например, "PR" или "OB"), далее идут параметры, тип параметра определяется первой буквой слова ("L80", где L - тип параметра).

Собственно, вопрос:
как организовать временное хранение данных внутри программы (не на HDD), что бы обеспечить доступ рассчитывающим классам к каждому конкретному значению параметра, при этом знать, какому типу строки он принадлежит?

Вот наиболее очевидный способ (по крайней мере мне, с высоты моего незнания):
каждый тип строки - класс, содержащий поля, соответствующие параметрам строки;
все строки-классы исполняют интерфейс без конкретных методов.
чтобы организовать набор данных, объявляется массив объектов типа интерфейса, объекты (строки-классы) добавляются в массив по выбору пользователя;
доступ к данным производится по индексу массива, соответственно проверяется тип объекта, затем извлекаются значения параметров-полей.

Знаний пока не хватает, чтобы что-то иное придумать.

Какие способы, может быть более эффективные, обладающие некоторыми преимуществами, вы видите?

Примечание:
Реальная задача - расчет показателей работы ГПП. приведенный пример - это исходные данные (параметры работы). Т.е. необходимо брать каждый (необходимый для расчета определенного показателя) параметр и использовать его в качестве аргумента рассчитывающего метода. 
Задача парсинга как такового пока не стоит. с этим проще разобраться. Цель всего этого - организовать удобный ввод данных пользователем. ввод в текстовый файл - по моему не слишком удобно.

Comment: - Спарсить такой файл несложно, другое дело, что хороший дизайн приложения можно придумать только в том случае, если известно, что вы будете делать с этими данными.
- Вот, допустим, вам в какой-то момент времени пришла штуковина, закодированная как `OB L10 H15 S30.5 K31`. Что вы хотите с ней делать? Зависит ли эффект от этой штуки от того, что пришло до этого? Есть ли у вас некоторый конечный автомат или вся логика завязана на **одну команду,** пришедшую в данный момент времени?

Comment: - Наиболее универсальным (на мой взгляд) будет декодировать команду в момент необходимости ее `evaluation'a`, то есть протягивать *строчку* или какую-нибудь простую обертку для нее до момента, когда она может на что-либо влиять, и в этот момент времени производить `decode + execute.`

- Естественно, что все это неточно и просто предположение (в силу того, что вы не написали задачу, решаемую вашей программой - вряд ли "прочитать, встретить определенные символы, определить тип строки" точно описывает вашу **реальную задачу**).

Comment: Реальная задача - расчет показателей работы ГПП. приведенный пример - это исходные данные (параметры работы). Т.е. необходимо брать каждый (необходимый для расчета определенного показателя) параметр и использовать его в качестве аргумента рассчитывающего метода.
Задача парсинга как такового пока не стоит. с этим проще разобраться. Цель всего этого - организовать удобный ввод данных пользователем. ввод в текстовый файл - по моему не слишком удобно.

Answer (score 2):

У вас слишком все сложно, оверинжиниринг детектед. Можно например так: (далеко не самый лучший вариант).

```
class MyString
{
byte type; //Один из шести типов
boolean isUnique; //Строка уникальная?
int[] values; //Значения параметров для всех типов
string data; //Вся строка
}

String[] getTypeStringFromIndex  = {"IM","PR","OB" и.т.д};
String[] getParametrStringFromIndex = {"N","L","H" и.т.д};

ArrayList<MyString> list = new ArrayList<MyString>(); //Массив строк

//list заполняется по результатом лексического/синтаксического анализа входного файла, автоматически сгенерированным парсером. Соответствие между индексом и значением параметра/типа строки первоначально определяется там.
```

Comment: Ну да, правильно это вполне в стиле oldschool - одобряю. + от меня. Уверен внутрях все так и реализовано

Answer (score 2):

Узнаю олдскул: [Клиппер/Clipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(programming_language)) это да - жосткая весчь была. Выкормила не одно поколение программеров - по сути клон знаменитого [dBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase) выродившегося в ходе многолетних эпопей в мертвый ныне [Foxpro](http://www.foxprohistory.org/foxprotimeline.htm).

Возвращаясь к теме вопроса: мыслите в правильном направлении, только я бы еще отяготил данное безобразие JavaBeans'ами + хорошей рефлексией - тогда у вас не будет:

> все строки-классы исполняют интерфейс
> без конкретных методов